# npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS when using npm to show the webpack info

Tags: npm, webpack

when I am using npm to show the webpack version in macOS like this:

```
npm list webpack
```

show error like this:

```
├─┬ babel-loader@6.4.1
│ └── webpack@5.66.0 deduped invalid: "1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/babel-loader
├─┬ extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
│ └── webpack@5.66.0 deduped invalid: "1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/babel-loader, "^1.9.11" from node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin
├─┬ karma-webpack@1.8.1
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2
│ │ └── webpack@5.66.0 deduped invalid: "1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/babel-loader, "^1.9.11" from node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin, "^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/karma-webpack, "^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0" from node_modules/karma-webpack/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware
│ └── webpack@5.66.0 deduped invalid: "1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/babel-loader, "^1.9.11" from node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin, "^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/karma-webpack
├─┬ webpack-cli@4.9.1
│ ├─┬ @webpack-cli/configtest@1.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.66.0 deduped invalid: "1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/babel-loader, "^1.9.11" from node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin, "^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/karma-webpack, "^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0" from node_modules/karma-webpack/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware
│ └── webpack@5.66.0 deduped invalid: "1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/babel-loader, "^1.9.11" from node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin, "^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/karma-webpack
└─┬ webpack@5.66.0 invalid: "1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/babel-loader, "^1.9.11" from node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin, "^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/karma-webpack
  └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.0
    └── webpack@5.66.0 deduped invalid: "1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/babel-loader, "^1.9.11" from node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin, "^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc" from node_modules/karma-webpack, "^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0" from node_modules/karma-webpack/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: webpack@5.66.0 /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/crx-selection-translate/node_modules/webpack

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.npm/_logs/2022-01-15T14_25_30_098Z-debug.log
```

why tell me the webpack version was invalid? why would this happen? what should I do to fix it?